# Is there a way to get rid of the horizontal dark padding?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Im trying to use almost all the space horizontally within the dark container to use almost all of it's width with the white col. Is there a way to get rid of the preset padding by Bootstrap?

```
<div class="col pt-5 text-center bg-warning text-light">Main
                    <div style="height:400px;"  class="row bg-dark">
                        <div class="col-5 bg-white mt-4 text-dark">Article</div>
                        <div class="col bg-white mt-4 text-dark">Article</div>
                    </div>
```

no-gutter did do it for me

here the full code...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bloques con Bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
            <div>
                <div class="container text-center bg-dark p-3">
                    <div class="text-light bg-info col-3 offset-4 p-1">Header</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div style="height:300px;" class="col-4 text-center bg-info text-light pt-4">Aside</div>
                <div class="col pt-5 text-center bg-warning text-light">Main
                    <div style="height:400px;"  class="row bg-dark">
                        <div class="col-5 bg-white mt-4 text-dark">Article</div>
                        <div class="col bg-white mt-4 text-dark">Article</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="bg-success text-center text-light py-3">Footer</div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @konekoya I added it now

Comment: Could you put this in a codesanbox or a Git repo which can repro the problem you are facing?

Comment: @konekoya turns out it was white space in the HTML file, I wasn't aware that white space on HTML would affect the visual result on Bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `mt-4` use `pt-4`.
margin will not do what you want

```
<div class="col pt-5 text-center bg-warning text-light">Main
                <div style="height:400px;"  class="row bg-dark">
                    <div class="col-5 h-100 bg-white pt-4 text-dark">Article</div>
                    <div class="col h-100 bg-white pt-4 text-dark">Article</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/